# How do you implement custom delegates in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, delegates, swiftui, delegation

As an example I have a SwitUI ContentView. The one that comes when you first make the project.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
   var manager = TestManager()
   var body: some View {
    ZStack{
        Color(.green)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        VStack {
            Text("Test Text")

            Button(action:{}) {
                Text("Get number 2")
                    .font(.title)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                .padding()
                .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30)
                .stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 5))
                }
           }
       }
   }
}
```

I have a TestManager that will handle an Api call. I Made a delegate for the class that has two functions.

```
protocol TestManagerDelegate {
    func didCorrectlyComplete(_ testName: TestManager, model: TestModel)
    func didFailWithError(_ error: Error)
}

struct TestManager {

    var delegate: TestManagerDelegate?
    let urlString = "http://numbersapi.com/2/trivia?json"

    func Get(){
        if let url = URL(string: urlString){

            let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)

            let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
                if error != nil{
                    self.delegate?.didFailWithError(error!)
                    return
                }

                if let safeData = data{
                    if let parsedData = self.parseJson(safeData){
                        self.delegate?.didCorrectlyComplete(self, model: parsedData)
                    }
                }
            }
            task.resume()
        }
    }

   func parseJson(_ jsonData: Data) -> TestModel?{
       let decoder = JSONDecoder()
       do {
           let decodedData = try decoder.decode(TestModel.self,  from: jsonData)
           let mes = decodedData.message
           let model = TestModel(message: mes)
           return model

       } catch {
           delegate?.didFailWithError(error)
           return nil
       }
     }

  }
```

This is the testModel data class. Only grabbing the text of the Json returned.

```
struct TestModel :Decodable{
    let text: String
}
```

How do I connect the TestManager to the view and have the view handle the delegate like how we could do in in storyboards?

Comment: Look for MVVM pattern - it is more natural for SwiftUI than delegate, ie you can use ViewModel as a clue between view and manager; of course, it can play delegate role as well, but looks redundant for me.

Comment: I looked up MVVM so it is basically the same thing as the ObservableObject answer that I marked below as correct? Its not all the same steps but similar enough that it follows the same pattern of binding the view to ViewModel?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Regarding the TestModel

[Decodable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/decodable) protocol (in your context) assumes you to create the model struct with all the properties, that you get via JSON. When requesting `http://numbersapi.com/2/trivia?json` you'll get something like:

```
{
 "text": "2 is the number of stars in a binary star system (a stellar system consisting of two stars orbiting around their center of mass).",
 "number": 2,
 "found": true,
 "type": "trivia"
}
```

Which means, your model should look like the following:

```swift
struct TestModel: Decodable {
    let text: String
    let number: Int
    let found: Bool
    let type: String
}
```

### Regarding Delegates

In SwiftUI this approach is not reachable. Instead, developers need to adapt the Combine framework's features: property wrappers `@ObservedObject`, `@Published`, and `ObservableObject` protocol. 
You want to put your logic into some struct. Bad news, that (currently) `ObservableObject` is `AnyObject` protocol (i.e. [Class-Only Protocol](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Protocols.html#ID281)). You'll need to rewrite your `TestManager` as class as:

```swift
class TestManager: ObservableObject {
   // ...
}
```

Only then you could use it in your `CurrentView` using [@ObservedObject](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/observedobject) property wrapper:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var manager = TestManager()
    // ...
}
```

#### Regarding the TestManager

Your logic now excludes the `delegate` as such, and you need to use your `TestModel` to pass the data to your `CustomView`. You could modify `TestManager` by adding new property with [@Published](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/published) property wrapper:

```swift
class TestManager: ObservableObject {
    let urlString = "http://numbersapi.com/2/trivia?json"
    // 1
    @Published var model: TestModel?

    func get(){
        if let url = URL(string: urlString){
            let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
            let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { [weak self] (data, response, error) in
                // 2
                DispatchQueue.main.async { 
                    if let safeData = data {
                        if let parsedData = self?.parseJson(safeData) {
                            // 3
                            self?.model = parsedData
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            task.resume()
        }
    }

    private func parseJson(_ jsonData: Data) -> TestModel? {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        do {
            let decodedData = try decoder.decode(TestModel.self, from: jsonData)
            return decodedData
        } catch {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

1. To be able to access your model "from outside", in your case the `ContentView`.
2. Use `DispatchQueue.main.async{ }` for async tasks, because `Publishing changes from background threads is not allowed; make sure to publish values from the main thread (via operators like receive(on:)) on model updates.`
3. Simply use your parsed model.

Then in `ContentView` use your `TestManager` like this:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var manager = TestManager()
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            Color(.green)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            VStack {
                Text("Trivia is: \(self.manager.model?.text ?? "Unknown")")
                Button(action:{ self.manager.get() }) {
                    Text("Get number 2")
                        .font(.title)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .padding()
                        .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30)
                            .stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 5))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Regarding HTTP

You use the link `http://numbersapi.com/2/trivia?json` which is [not allowed by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/nsapptransportsecurity), please, use `https` instead, or add the `App Transport Security Settings` key with `Allow Arbitrary Loads` parameter set to `YES` [into your Info.Plist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40299837/1040347). But do this [very carefully](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/nsapptransportsecurity/nsallowsarbitraryloads) as the http link simply will not work.

#### Further steps

You could implement the error handling by yourself basing on the description above.

#### Full code (copy-paste and go):

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var manager = TestManager()
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            Color(.green)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            VStack {
                Text("Trivia is: \(self.manager.model?.text ?? "Unknown")")
                Button(action:{ self.manager.get() }) {
                    Text("Get number 2")
                        .font(.title)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .padding()
                        .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30)
                            .stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 5))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

class TestManager: ObservableObject {
    let urlString = "http://numbersapi.com/2/trivia?json"
    @Published var model: TestModel?

    func get(){
        if let url = URL(string: urlString){
            let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
            let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { [weak self] (data, response, error) in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    if let safeData = data {
                        if let parsedData = self?.parseJson(safeData) {
                            self?.model = parsedData
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            task.resume()
        }
    }

    private func parseJson(_ jsonData: Data) -> TestModel? {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        do {
            let decodedData = try decoder.decode(TestModel.self, from: jsonData)
            return decodedData
        } catch {
            return nil
        }
    }
}

struct TestModel: Decodable {
    let text: String
    let number: Int
    let found: Bool
    let type: String
}
```

Comment: Is using the ObservableObject the way we should be using SwiftUi when we are trying to fetch data and return it to our views? Is their another way in SwiftUI that lets us do basically the same thing or is this the best way we currently have?

Comment: For the needs described in this question - the approach using ObservableObject is the only way.